# "Пертурбации"

Tags: этимология

Еще интересует происхождение слова "пертурбации". Это иностранное слово или русское?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пертурбация**, -и [не перетурбация]. Слово латинского происхождения [от лат. perturbatio - расстройство, возмущение] 1. *Книжн*. Внезапное изменение, осложнение в ходе чего-л., вносящее расстройство, неупорядоченность, диссонанс. *Исторические пертурбации. Пертурбации в языке. Жизненные пертурбации.* 2. *Спец*. Отклонение небесных тел от своей орбиты под воздействием силы притяжения других тел. *Пертурбация кометы.*